# What does it mean to have an over-sized motor?

Tags: electric-current, voltage, torque, electromagnetic-induction, power

What does it mean to have an oversized motor?

I have read that the Power consumed by a motor under various load conditions is not constant according to the answers to this question (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149296/is-power-consumed-by-a-motor-under-various-load-conditions-constant)
So, the motor only provides the exact amount of power required by the load by changing the amount of current drawn from the supply source according to the torque.

So, why do we need to worry about an oversized motor?

Answer (score 1):

These graphs show the efficiency against percentage full load for motor with a  different horsepower (hp) rating.

[image]

You will note that the efficiency (useful mechanical power output / electrical power input) drops by a lot if a motor is run below 50$ 0f its rating with the optimum load rating between 60% and 80%.
This range is larger for motors with a higher power rating.

Mechanical losses at the bearings and aerodynamic losses do not change much with loading and so as a percentage of the total power input become more significant at lower end of useful mechanical power output.

When the loading is high resistive losses in windings become a much more significant factor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to think about this which may be easier for you to grasp.

The power output of a motor is zero at zero rpm (power on, shaft locked) and again zero at zero applied load (power on, motor running free at max rpm). Remember that power = torque x rpm, so somewhere between the locked-shaft condition and the no-load condition the power output of the motor will go through a maximum. This maximum point is the *rated power output* of the motor as designed and manufactured: x horsepower at y rpm.

To double the power output of a motor at a given RPM requires twice the torque which translates into a motor that weighs about twice as much and therefore costs about twice as much. So to *minimize the motor cost to perform a given job* ( x HP @ y RPM) you specify the *smallest motor* that can produce the needed output.

Buying a motor with more output than this will cost more money and provide no additional benefit except for those cases where a little more power is needed for a short amount of time. This is the *oversized-motor* case.

Oversizing the motor makes sense for tools like a table saw, where you want to keep cutting even when you hit a hard knot in the board which would otherwise bog down the motor. It does *not* make sense for a motor used in a constant-load application like running an air fan or a constant-pressure water pump. It also makes sense for a motor that has to set something heavy in motion when initially turned on (i.e., it has a large *startup load*) like an electric grinding wheel with two big heavy wheels on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the power consumed is not constant.  As the load is reduced, the input power is also lower.

But that doesn't mean that the reduction is linear (and the question you link to doesn't say that it is).  Motors have losses, some of them are fixed.  Usually as you operate a motor far away from maximum load, the percentage of the loss increases.

At a given load, you would expect that a larger motor would have a greater power consumption than a smaller motor.  The larger motor can handle larger loads.  But if they are not needed, it will consume more power.